# How to use TreeView in Kivy?

Tags: python, treeview, kivy

I'm deving an app which requires a TreeView on the home menu. I want to add a node on a button click in my TreeView. When I click on the button to add a node to the treeview, I get an error. 
(I'm trying to discover the TreeView widget but I can't implement it even with the docs)

**gui_test.py:**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class UI(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Screen1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen1, self).__init__(**kwargs)


Builder.load_file("gui_test.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return UI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**gui_test.kv:**

```
#: kivy 1.10.0

<UI>:
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"

        BoxLayout:

            TreeView:
                id: tv

            Button:
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                text: "add_node"
                on_press: tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text = "Node..."))
```

**output error when I click on the button:**

```
(...)
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8146)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1225, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:14035)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1109, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy\_event.c:12816)
   File "C:\Users\hnnc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\hnnc\Documents\Interpreter\GUI_TEST\gui_test.kv", line 16, in <module>
     on_press: tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text = "Node..."))
 NameError: name 'TreeViewLabel' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, you only need to [import](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes) `TreeViewLabel` class in your kv file:

```
#: kivy 1.10.0
#: import TreeViewLabel kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewLabel


<UI>:
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"

        BoxLayout:

            TreeView:
                id: tv

            Button:
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint: (None, None)
                text: "add_node"
                on_press: tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text = "Node..."))
```